# How convert Record Separator character into line break

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, python-unicode

Hello i'm using for this porpouse pyspark
I have a txt file that contains this information

```
c-234r4|Julio|38|Madrida-533r2|Ana|32|Madrida-543r4|Sonia|33|Bilbaob-654r4|Jorge|23|Barcelona
```

If you see all records are concateneted using the Record Separator character **([see this link](https://unicode-table.com/en/001E/))**

I'm trying to do this, but without results

```
df = spark.read.load("s3://my-bucket/txt_file/data.txt", format="csv", sep="|", inferSchema="true", encoding="UTF-8", escape='U+001E')


df.show(10, False)
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o496.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: escape cannot be more than one character
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.getChar(CSVOptions.scala:52)
```

the final result must be looks like this:

```
+-------+-----+---+--------------+
|_c0    |_c1  |_c2|_c3           |
+-------+-----+---+--------------+
|c-234r4|Julio|38 |Madrid        |
|a-533r2|Ana  |32 |Madrid        |
|a-543r4|Sonia|33 |Bilbao        |
|b-654r4|Jorge|23 |Barcelona     |
+-------+-----+---+--------------+
```

**Options tested:**

***option-1*** --> This totally wrong

[image]

***option-2*** --> This show rows as columns ... and this is wrong

[image]

---

Can somebody give me an advice i need an idea to resolve this on my actual role?

I'll appreciete

Thanks

Comment: try replacing your escape char with : `u"\u001E"`. This should fixe the error but using `escape` option is not what you are looking for. Escape is used to escape quotes...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try modifying the scape parameter , but i can get it, (see this link)[https://imgur.com/MNLFDij ] and you will see the result. There is another option ?